# PHP 5.3 strange behaviour on static:: late binding

Tags: php, yii, php-5.3

```
<?php

class baseModel
{
    public static function show($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        print_r($className);
    }

    public function test()
    {
        static::show();
    }
}

class AModel extends baseModel 
{
    public static function show($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        print_r($className);
    }
}

class Controller
{
    public function actionTest()
    {
        baseModel::test();
        AModel::test();
    }
}

$c = new Controller;
$c->actionTest();
?>
```

Expected output:

```
baseModelAModel
```

Actual output:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Controller::show() in /var/www/dashboard/test.php on line 12
```

Why did PHP try to find `Controller::show()` rather than `AModel::show`?

Comment: Thanks, Amal. I was just trying to fix format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` keyword refers to context, not the class the method was defined in. So, when you call `A::test` from context of C, `static` refers to C.

Comment: easiest ways are to inherit class C from A or incapsulate instance of A in C.

Comment: But I can't. I am using Yii. The actual code include two models, one extends another one. class C is the controller so it cannot extends base or A. I'll update test code a bit later.

Comment: seems like `test` method isn't static in your models. So you can just instantiate them and directly call the `test` method: `$model = new AModel; $model->test();`.

Comment: Yes, convert all static method to non-static methods can work. But I would prefer to keep it static if possible as there would be 2 lines of code vs 1 line of code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As it writes in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

> **In non-static contexts**, the called class will be the class of the object instance. Since $this-> will try to call private methods from the same scope, **using static:: may give different results**. Another difference is that static:: can only refer to static properties.

This means that in context of object `$c` (class `Controller`) making a non-static call (`$c->t()`) late binding `static::` keyword in method `baseModel::test()` references class of object reference `$this` which is `Controller` and not called class, while if calling static:

```
Controller::test();
```

Context of `static::` is called class.

I would however advise you not to use static calls unless methods are explicitly defined as static:

```
class baseModel
{
    public static function show($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        print_r($className);
    }

    public static function test() 
    // must be defined as static or context of static:: may change to Controller instead of actual class being called!
    {
        static::show();
    }
}
```

This code works because if defining explicitly `baseModel::test()` as being static context of `static::` will always be static.